# How to scale up and down Azure Cosmos DB using some scripts like power shell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-cosmosdb

How to scale up and down Azure Cosmos DB using some scripts like power shell or by any method. I want to increase the RU's of the Cosmos DB in my script when I run it. I think we can do it using Azure functions but looking for more options

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no Azure Power Shell could manage Azure Cosmos DB collection. Please refer to this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/13379637-manage-azure-documentdb-using-powershell).

Currently, you could use [Azure CLI 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest)(based on python) to increase RU.

For [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/scripts/scale-collection-throughput-cli).

```
# Scale throughput
az cosmosdb collection update \
    --collection-name $collectionName \
    --name $name \
    --db-name $databaseName \
    --resource-group $resourceGroupName \
    --throughput $newThroughput
```

If you want to use Power Shell to do this, you need call API. This [blog](http://sql-articles.com/articles/azure/cosmos-db/provisioning-azure-cosmos-db-using-powershell/) will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Up until now, you can use the azure-cosmos Python SDK to interface with the Azure Cosmos DB.

Answer (score -1):

You can scale RU's with Azure CLI
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/scripts/scale-collection-throughput-cli